# Splitting a layer containing multiple polygons into multiple layers each containing one polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, point-in-polygon

So firstly, I used the buffer tool in Qgis3 to create (twenty) polygons with a certain width from (twenty) points.
This lead to the situation below, where o1 and o2 are two original points and 1 and 2 are the resulting polygons.
Now, I want points (like A in the picture below) from another point layer to have an attribute stating in which polygon they are. However, in overlapping situations I would like to see both polygon id's to be added, which does not happen when using the 'add polygon attribute to point' (which only adds one polygon id).

[image: layer with polygons like this]

To resolve this, I need to have a different layer for each polygon, so I can use dummy variables. How do I create a different layer for each polygon? I have heard of the Split Polygon plug-in in Qgis2, but I am working in Qgis3. To clarify, I would like for both polygons to be kept intact, as I've seen others wanting the overlapping section belonging to only one of the polygons.

Comment: Have you chosen `one-to-many` when joining the attributes by location?

Comment: Hi, thanks @vagvaf ! I think I was using the wrong key words when searching when looking for the solution. By the way, do you agree with the thought process in my post? I am pretty new to Qgis and was wondering if this is how you go about things.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your comment! I had rested this part of the project, but upon closer inspection your method works. (I had seen your comment, but I could not locate that option.) Quick question, what happens if a point is in two polygons? I see only one polygon id gets added to the point, so is that the polygon with the nearest centre? Thanks again!